# Read xml data in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this T-SQL script:

```
DECLARE @idoc int

DECLARE @doc nvarchar(200)
SET @doc ='<ArrayOfString>
            <string>AL</string>
            <string>DZ</string>
        </ArrayOfString>'

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;

    select *  
    FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/ArrayOfString',2)
    WITH (string varchar(50))
    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

This is a stored procedure. I send to it some serialized xml (in this variant I declare it as hard code).

I want to get all `<string>` element's values. In this variant it must be: `AL` and `DZ`, but I get only 'AL'. What is it incorrect in my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `OPENXML` try this:

```
DECLARE @idoc int

DECLARE @doc nvarchar(200)
SET @doc ='<ArrayOfString>
            <string>AL</string>
            <string>DZ</string>
        </ArrayOfString>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;

select *  
    FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/ArrayOfString/string',2)
    WITH (string varchar(50) '.')

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Answer (score 5):

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '<ArrayOfString 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <string>Dev_1</string>
    <string>Dev_3</string>
</ArrayOfString>'

SELECT 
    T.C.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)')
from @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfString/string') T(C)
```

Comment: Thanks.It's variant work good! But, What is 'T.C.value' and T(C) in your code?

Comment: "T(C)" is alias for "@xml.nodes('/ArrayOfString/string')" in the last statement.

Comment: Good! But if it is alias, why we write 'T.C.value'? Sorry, if its silly question! :)

Comment: It is used fetch the value or content from XML node.